# How can we track click on link tags inside amp story pages

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, amp-html, amp-analytics, amp-stories

I have a amp story where I have also implemented tracking with Google Analytics. Events such as story-page-visible are working perfectly. But when I tried to track the click event on an anchor tag inside my story page it does not work.These are my triggers and anchor tag:

UPDATED CODE

```
 <amp-analytics type="gtag" data-credentials="include">
        <script type="application/json">
        {
          "vars": {
            "gtag_id": "UA-YYYY-Y",
            "event_category": "<%= storyName %>",
            "config": {
              "UA-YYYY-Y": {
                "groups": "default"
              }
            }
          },
          "extraUrlParams": {
            "cd75": "AMP",
            "cd69": "AMP",
            "cd81": "marketplace",
            "cd76": "${ampdocHostname}"
          },
          "triggers": {
            "linkClick" : {
              "on": "click",
              "selector": "a",
              "request": "event",
              "vars": {
                "eventCategory" : "click"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      </script>
    </amp-analytics>
```

```
 <a href="https://amp.dev/" >
                <p>click here to read more</p>
            </a>
```

No event is fired on click of anchor tag or on click of tooltip.Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: potentially adding the actual story code might shed some light on the error. I would also check if your trigger is firing on link clicks outside of the story tag - is it an isolated issue only within then?  also any console errors? your example should work i think given thats the exact example given in the docs https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-analytics/#click-trigger

Answer (score 2):

I tried your example and it seems to work. I'm posting the full configuration I used so you can compare with yours.
Also, did you add the amp-analytics script in the head of your document?

```
<script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
```

--

```
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics">
<script type="application/json">
{
  "vars": {
    "account": "UA-YYYY-Y"
  },
  "triggers": {
    "default click": {
      "on": "click",
      "selector": "a",
      "request": "event",
      "vars": {
        "eventCategory": "amp click"
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```

Here you have a typo and forgot to close the `</p>` tag, but it should work nonetheless.

```
<a href="https://amp.dev/" >
  <p>click here to read more</p>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried ur code and it works. I think my issue is because I am using  `type="gtag"`. When I am trying with  `type="googleanalytics"` the click events are fired but pageview is not fired. I am still  new at this can anyone help me what is the difference between using `gtag` and `googleanalytics`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue adding **event_name** in triggers fixed the issue

```
   <amp-analytics type="gtag" data-credentials="include">
    <script type="application/json">
    {
      "vars": {
        "gtag_id": "UA-YYYY-Y",
        "event_category": "<%= storyName %>",
        "config": {
          "UA-YYYY-Y": {
            "groups": "default"
          }
        }
      },
      "extraUrlParams": {
        "cd75": "AMP",
        "cd69": "AMP",
        "cd81": "marketplace",
        "cd76": "${ampdocHostname}"
      },
      "triggers": {
        "linkClick" : {
          "on": "click",
          "selector": "a",
          "request": "event",
          "vars": {
            "event_name" : "login",
            "eventCategory" : "click"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</amp-analytics>
```